# Print duration of every step in terminal, during watir-cucumber execution

Tags: cucumber, watir, scenarios

Is there a standard way of printing the duration of every step in the terminal, during a watir-cucumber execution?

[image]
It might be possible to make some kind of invention, using the "after step" and a global variable. But, there is a proper way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use hooks like this:

```
Before do 
  @last_time = Time.new  
end

AfterStep do
  now = Time.new
  puts "Step duration: #{((now - @last_time)*100).round} ms"    # if (now-@last_time) > 10        
  @last_time = now
end
```

This is more verbose by outputting the duration on a new line, but unless you want to get more in-depth (by creating your own formatter), you cannot output stuff where you indicated it.

Uncomment the `if` if you are only interested in steps that take longer than a certain threshold.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be using Ruby's built in Time class. Using Time.new we can record the current time into a local variable before and after the code within the step definition is executed. Then we work out the duration by subtracting start_time from end_time.

```
#get the start time
 start_time = Time.new

#do whatever the step needs to do here

#get the end time
 end_time = Time. new

#calculate duration 
duration = end_time - start_time
puts duration
```

Comment: With big project, you have hundred of step_definitions. This method is good if you want information for a particular function, but not for all.

Comment: Something like this may work, if the code is contained in the "after step".